# Variance inflation factor for generalized additive models

Tags: regression, variance, multicollinearity, generalized-additive-model, variance-inflation-factor

In the usual VIF calculation for a linear regression, each independent/explanatory variable $X_j$ is treated as the dependent variable in an ordinary least squares regression. i.e.

$$
X_j = \beta_0 + \sum_{i=1, i \neq j}^n \beta_i X_i
$$

The $R^2$ values are stored for each of the $n$ regressions and VIF is determined by

$$
VIF_j = \frac{1}{1-R^2_j}
$$

for a particular explanatory variable.

Suppose my generalize additive model takes the form, 
$$
Y=\beta_0+ \sum_{i=1}^n \beta_iX_i + \sum_{j=1}^m s_j(X_i) .
$$

Is there an equivalent VIF calculation for this type of model?
Is there a way I can control for the smooth terms $s_j$ to test for multicollinearity?

Answer (score 1):

There is a function in r `corvif()` which can be found in `AED` package.  For examples and  references see Zuur et al. 2009. Mixed Effects Models and Extensions in Ecology with R  pp. 386-387.  The code for the package is available from the book website http://www.highstat.com/book2.htm.

Comment: You'll get my vote if you spruce up your answer with some of the math. :)

Comment: @Alexis is right. This is helpful, but note that the question isn't asking for R code. Can you explain the application of the VIF to GAMs conceptually?